# Como llamar variables de un void en otro void

Tags: c++

Tengo un problema al llamar la información de un **void** en otro **void**. Tengo un menú con tres **voids**, en el ***void1*** solicito escribir un texto y guarda la cantidad de vocales de ese texto, también debo preguntar si desea comenzar de nuevo o si desea volver al menú principal. En el ***void2*** debo mostrar el ultimo texto escrito en el void1 junto con la cantidad de vocales de ese texto. Y en el **void3** debo mostrar la cantidad de veces que se ingreso un texto y cuantas vocales se cantabilizaron en su totalidad. No sé como hacer para llevar esa información de un lado a otro, soy nueva en el tema de la programación y me ha llevado dos semanas resolver ese problema. Alguien me podría ayudar por favor.

Adjunto una parte del **código**:

```cpp
void Ingresar_palabra()
{
         setlocale(LC_ALL, ""); 
         bool repetir = true; 
         system ("CLS");

                char palabra[100];
                int i=0;
                int contvocal=0, contador=0, acumulador=0;
                int opc2;

               do{
                cout << "Ingrese una frase: " << endl;

                cin.ignore(110, '\n');

                cin.getline(palabra,100);
                      contador=contador+1;

                for (int i=0; i<strlen(palabra); i++) 
                {
                   switch(palabra[i])
                      {
                     
                       case 'a': contvocal++; break; case 'A': contvocal++; break;
                       case 'e': contvocal++; break; case 'E': contvocal++; break;
                       case 'i': contvocal++; break; case 'I': contvocal++; break;
                       case 'o': contvocal++; break; case 'O': contvocal++; break;
                       case 'u': contvocal++; break; case 'U': contvocal++; break;
                       case 'á': contvocal++; break; case 'Á': contvocal++; break;
                       case 'é': contvocal++; break; case 'É': contvocal++; break;
                       case 'í': contvocal++; break; case 'Í': contvocal++; break;
                       case 'ó': contvocal++; break; case 'Ó': contvocal++; break;
                       case 'ú': contvocal++; break; case 'Ú': contvocal++; break;
                    }
               }
                   acumulador= acumulador+contvocal;
                 cout << "TOTAL GENERAL DE VOCALES: " << contvocal << endl;
                 cout << "TOTAL DE FRASES INGRESADAS: " << acumulador << endl;
                 cout << " " << endl;
                 cout << " " << endl;
    cout << "Desea regresar al menú principal (1.Si) (2.No): " << endl;
    cin >> opc2;

    if( !cin.good())
        {
          
          cout << "Opción inválida, vuelva a intentarlo ..." <<endl;

          cin.clear();

          cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');
          system("PAUSE");

          system("CLS");
        }
        else{ 
       switch (opc2)
      {
      case 1:
        {
            return Menu_principal();
            break;
        }
      case 2:
        {
            return Resultados_finales();
            break;
        }
      default:
        {
            cout << "Opción invalida, intente de nuevo ..." << endl;
            break;
        }
      }
        }
     } while (repetir); 

    system ("PAUSE"); 
}
```

Comment: No puedes acceder a las variables de otra función. Sí puedes acceder a una variable en el ámbito global desde *casi" cualquier parte del código. O pasar por parámetro las variables correspondientes. Además, el código no debería compilar ya que no puedes usar `return` con el resultado de una función `void` ya que no devuelve nada.

Comment: *"Tengo un menú con tres voids"* -> No, tienes un menú con tres *funciones* que no devuelven nada (void significa literalmente vacío, nada). Llamar a las cosas por su nombre es muy importante, esforzarse en hacerlo sobre todo al principio, hará que pronto seas capaz de explicar lo que te pasa con detalle. Si inventas los nombres de las cosas, entenderte costará más tiempo, te será más difícil explicar cosas y no entenderás cuando te expliquen algo. Acostúmbrate a usar los nombres correctos de las cosas :)